# Error updating UITableView after smaller sized JSON response?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Currently, I have my app hitting my endpoints, and getting back 10 or less items. In the event the items returned is less than 10, and the `UITableView` is already showing 10 items, `reloadData()` will cause an error because the size is not the same as it was last time. Right now, when I get my response all I do is:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.items = items //where self.items is the array that backs the UITableView, and items are the items I got back in form of JSON from the server.
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why will it cause error? If you are using tableView.reloadData(), you don't need to call endUpdates() and beginUpdates(). Just simply assign the items and reload tableView data.

`self.items = items 
tableView.reloadData()`

If you are on the background thread call the above code on the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            // Code runs on main queue!
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I believe that is it. I thought beginUpdate and endUpdate were required.

Answer (score 2):

It is not your calling reloadData that caused error. It is because your numberOfRowsInSection or numberOfSectionsInTableView didn't return right value after you update your model.

Comment: But that's the thing, the parent controller (because I am extending this tableView from a base class I defined) has: 


```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (noPrediction) {
      return 1;
    }
    noPrediction = false
    return self.items.count
  }
```


So I am confused as to why it would fail. Also, I don't know why this code block isn't formatting >:(

Comment: Try removing tableView.beginUpdate() and tableView.endUpdate() as @Hassan Rafique Awan says may help.

Answer (score 0):

In the table view method,

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
```

you should write as , return [self.items count];

This way, your table will know, how many items your table need to show, and reload data would not complain.